# Azure Function - HTTP Trigger and Response - Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

Im working off of the Azure Function HTTP Python Template that has this code:

```
import os
import json

postreqdata = json.loads(open(os.environ['req']).read())
response = open(os.environ['res'], 'w')
response.write("hello world from "+postreqdata['name'])
response.close()
```

This all works great. But when trying to implement it in my python script package, the response never gets sent back.

Heres how my code looks:

```
import os
import json

postreqdata = json.loads(open(os.environ['req']).read())

while True:

mode = 0

 if mode == 0:

        response = open(os.environ['res'], 'w')
        response.write("Mode selected is 0, testing has begun.")
        response.close()
        test.testing()
```

As you can see my python script `test.testing()` is running in its own loop and runs successfully, but I never get the response back. Even if I put the "response" code last.

I simply want to call HTTP `POST`, which executes the script and get an OUTPUT of the

> "Mode selected is 0, testing has begun."

message only once, and let the `test.testing()` script work its magic while in a loop.

Im pretty sure im not getting the logic right, let me know if anyone can point me in the right direction. Python current version is 2.7 and dont want to upgrade to 3 for this.

Comment: You really shouldn't be using V1 python functions for anything that is production or critical. the Python support in functions v1 is very experimental and is pretty heavy weight and not performant.

Answer (score 0):

Functions are supposed to be short-lived, they shouldn't run long loops, and especially eternal loops.

The response is only sent when your function completed which, in my my understanding, never happens with the code above.

Get rid of `While` or add a `break`, and make sure the whole function execution time is below 5 minutes (or whatever your max expected response time is).

Comment: Thank you but I subscribe to a PayAsYouGo AppService account, which allows me to run functions continuously, which is a service I pay for. The 5 minute limit is for free or consumption level accounts. (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale)

Would you be able to confirm where I can add the break exactly?

Comment: The principle still applies though

Comment: Would you be able to confirm where I can add the break exactly?

Comment: No, I don't understand purpose of the whole while-if, hard to say what exactly you tried to achieve

Comment: I have other If mode == 1, 2, 3 etc below the code, should i post those too? Theyre just loops of other functions

Comment: Post the code where mode is changed and when the loop finishes, if it does

Comment: It basically runs for up to 2 hours then it pipes out info to the log with:  self.write_log(“Function completed”), but that code located in another .py script that’s being imported.

Comment: Should it then be the timer- or queue-triggered function instead of HTTP (with no response)?

Comment: The thing is, I want to be able to implement various HTTP responses based on how far along the script is. Maybe I might be going about this wrong. But in the bigger picture, id have an app place a POST to the Azure function with data, the function picks up the POST, activates the script, uses the POST INPUT for the script. Then the script will respond based on different functions being executed.